# Emit and catch double-click signals from QgsMapCanvas

Tags: python, canvas, pyqt, double-click, qgis

I am using a QgsRubberBand, a QgsMapCanvas and a QgsMapToolEmitPoint. Combining those three I can successfully catch the event of canvasClicked and get the points I am interested in when I click on the canvas. I also can successfully use the QgsRubberBand to create points and lines using the left mouse click to get the vertices I want, to connect for making the line, and the right click to undo the last point.

All I need to do now is to finish my sketch when I double-click, instead of single-clicking on the canvas. I cannot connect any signal to it or even if I do so, I cannot see any double-click signal emited by anything. All I ask for, is a workaround to emit and recognize a double-click signal from the QgsMapCanvas.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: well i tried to connect keydown event from mapCanvas but it does nothing, also i tried to overload the QgsClickTool doubleClickEvent but it failed also. i can provide more info later, i am still working on this. it seems like the canvas is not emiting the keyDownEvent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The QgsMapToolEmitPoint class inherits QgsMapTool, which in turn has a [canvasDoubleClickEvent](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapTool.html#a4d1ce211ce8e642e453ffdf614e29a02) method. This method is virtual, so you could reimplement it in a subclass and emit a custom signal. Try something like this:

```
class MapToolEmitPoint(QgsMapToolEmitPoint):
    canvasDoubleClicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object, object)

    def canvasDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
        point = self.toMapCoordinates(event.pos())            
        self.canvasDoubleClicked.emit(point, event.button())
        super(MapToolEmitPoint, self).canvasDoubleClickEvent(event)
```

The `canvasDoubleClicked` signal has been given the same signature as the existing `canvasClicked` signal, so you should be able to use it in the same way.

**EDIT**

Just to be clear, the above class is intended to be used like this:

```
        maptool = MapToolEmitPoint(self.canvas)
        self.canvas.setMapTool(maptool)
        maptool.canvasDoubleClicked.connect(self.handleDoubleClick)
        ....

    def handleDoubleClick(self, point, buttons):
        # do stuff with point and buttons
        ...
```

Comment: the event you are using here is supposed to be a QgsPoint and a Qt.MouseButton, but it's not. In order to get the Qt.MouseButton i am sending when i connect the tool with the function i have to pass one more parameter, that later gives me the next error.
"TypeError: canvasDoubleClickEvent() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)" @ekhumoro

Comment: from this: ("def canvasDoubleClickEvent(self, event):") i changed it to this" ("def canvasDoubleClickEvent(self,inc_point,inc_button):")

Comment: @dterpas. No. You seem to be confused about the difference between events and signals, which are completely different mechanisms. To use my example code, you need to connect to the custom signal `canvasDoubleClicked`, which sends a QgsPoint and MouseButtons (i.e. just like the existing `canvasClicked` signal). See my updated answer for clarification.

Comment: I found my problem thanks to your answer. Your answer is the generic version. in order to make it work i had to modify it a bit. i was using QObject.connect(self.clickTool, SIGNAL("canvasDoubleClicked(const QgsPoint &, Qt::MouseButton)"), self.addLineToSplit) but it was not working as i wanted it to. with your kind of connect it's fine.

Comment: if you want to edit your code i made the next changes in order to make it work. the event was a QgsPoint so i had to convert it to a QPoint using: point= self.toMapCoordinates(QPoint(event.x(),event.y())). In order to to use the event.button() you said i had to make my own mousebutton using : mouseButton = Qt.LeftButton and at least for the "event" you are sending i had to create this: q_Event = QMouseEvent(QEvent.MouseButtonDblClick,QPoint(event.x(),event.y()),mouseButton,Qt.MouseButtons(1),Qt.KeyboardModifiers(1))
        super(MapToolEmitPoint,self).canvasDoubleClickEvent(q_Event)

Comment: @dterpas. You are completely wrong in every way. Look at the documentation for [canvasDoubleClickEvent](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapTool.html#a4d1ce211ce8e642e453ffdf614e29a02): the `event` argument is a `QMouseEvent`. Also, the [toMapCoordinates](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapTool.html#a3340999b5da5020491201f590e4d7ce4) method _returns_ a `QgsPoint`, so your "conversion" is totally redundant (and the same goes for all the other code in your comment).

Comment: i am trying to undersatand and accept what you say. But when i printed the type of the event i was passing, it was a QgsPoint, and if i passed a second parameter, it was a MouseButon. I might have lost something in the way. It seems redundant to me as well but at the momment it was the only thing that worked. About the conversion, i was getting an error that it expects a Qpoint and not a QgsPoint.

Comment: @dterpas. Fair enough. But just to be clear, what do you see if you add the line `print(event)` to the top of `canvasDoubleClickEvent` method of the `MapToolEmitPoint` class? If it's not a `QMouseEvent`, then it's either broken, or you're using an version of qgis that somehow differs from the documentation I referred to. Unfortunately, I can't test any of this myself at the moment.

Comment: i am printing it at the first line of the code just to be sure, and it is a QgsPoint sadly. Firstly i tried using it the way you had it but i had at least 1 error for each line sadly. But the good news is that your answer is the generic solution to the problem! with some minor adjustments.